# Populating ComboBox with Images inside folder in project

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok, the images are inside a folder that is "inside the project" and the build action is resource. My question is how do I put those icons in a comboBox?

And I think this is not a duplicate because I did search and only find results where the folder is not embedded in the project.

[image]

This is my code: (I got this from searching but I forgot the website)

```
List<object> items = new List<object>();
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourcesName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcesName);
var resourceReader = new ResourceReader(stream);
foreach(DictionaryEntry item in resourceReader)
{
    items.Add(item.Value);
}
comboBox.ItemsSource = items;

//it's working but this is what I get
icons/bbinq.ico
icons/bbt.ico
icons/begr.ico
icons/logo 1.ico
icons/logo.ico
icons/mepv1.ico
icons/mepv2.ico
icons/sbtm.ico

//what I need is like this (case sensitive also)
BBINQ.ico
BBT.ICO
BEGR.ico
LOGO 1.ICO
LOGO.ICO
MEPV1.ico
MEPV2.ico
SBTM.ICO
```

Comment: You just want to show the uppercase file name? Try `items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.Value).ToUpper());` Or probably `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`.

Comment: I believe you can use Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(userSuppliedName), Path.GetFileName(userSuppliedName)).FirstOrDefault(); to get the filename with case sensitivity. Then you will need to split out the name from the directory using string.split or GetFileName()

Comment: Is your question how to get the icons as images in a drop down box visually? Or just to get the filenames how you want?

Comment: just the filenames sir